# ImportError: cannot import name 'record_to_file' from 'utils'

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import a file named `record_to_file` from a file 'utils.py' saved in my system. I am trying to build a gender detection using voice analysis. but in file format its showing error.

This is the code:

```
from utils import load_data, record_to_file
```

The error showing is:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 3
      1 import argparse
      2 import os
----> 3 from utils import load_data, record_to_file
      4 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
      5 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

ImportError: cannot import name 'record_to_file' from 'utils' (C:\Users\mamta\GD-VA\utils.py)
```

In the utils.py file, the code for record_to_file:

```
def record_to_file(filename, duration=5, samplerate=44100, channels=2):
    """Record audio to a WAVE file."""
    print("Recording started...")
    myrecording = sd.rec(int(duration * samplerate), samplerate=samplerate, channels=channels)
    sd.wait()
    sf.write(filename, myrecording, samplerate)
    print("Recording finished.")
```

Comment: If it imports `load_data` but fails to import `record_to_file` from the same module, then it may be an issue of a stale cached version of the file. Try restarting the notebook kernel?

Comment: @slothrop already tried that several times

Comment: could it be a name clash with python-utils ? if so, you could rename your module